# Account Showing as Null after insert during a test

Tags: unit-test, account

I have written a helper class which is called from a trigger and a test to test it however my test isn't getting full coverage as it is showing the account attached to the asset is null however accountId has a value. What am I doing wrong?

Test:

```
Account testA = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
testA.OwnerId = testUser.Id
insert testA;

Asset testAss = new Asset(Name = 'Test Asset' + i,AccountId = testA.Id);
Test.startTest();
insert testAss;
Test.stopTest();
```

Helper Method that is called from trigger:

```
public static void CheckTest(List<Asset> assetList) {
    for (Asset a : assetList){  
        System.debug(a.AccountId);
        System.debug(a.Account);
        //... more stuff based off a.Account.Owner
    }
}
```

Obviously trigger.new get passed as a parameter into the above method.
Now the problem is that System.debug(a.Account) = null
whereas System.debug(a.AccountId) is not.
I have tried adding Account = testA into the creation of the asset and it made no difference.
(The above is not my actual code it is cut down for brevity, my actual code is bulkified and uses the accounts in a list and references them as such testAs[0])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `List<Asset>` is coming from a trigger, only the immediate field values of `Asset` are populated such as the ID of the Account `AccountId`. References to other objects such as `Account` are not populated in triggers; if you need values from other objects you have to explicitly query for them as part of your trigger logic.